# algorithm sorting 1101001011

Tags: php, c++, algorithm, sorting

I need to display picture and videos in some pre-defined order. How to get output predefined sorting from array.

```
$video = ['a1','a2','a3','a4'];
$picture = ['b1','b2','b3','b4'];
```

sort be like 
`[a,a,b,a,b,b,a,b,a,a];`

the result should be 
`['a1','a2','b1','a3','b2','b3',...];`

Comment: I see the pattern according you want to select the items from the two arrays. "1" means "take from $video array", and "0" means "take from $picture array". But, when to start with index 0 (zero), and when to continue with the previous index?

Comment: Please use more words and/or examples for _sort be like `[a,a,b,a,b,b,a,b,a,a];`_ - is that the result of the (your?) current approach? What is the connection to `$video` & `$picture`? And please explain _why_, in the example result, the is an `'a3'` (`'a1'` before the edit) between the `'b#'` - describe the desired order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially C++ present in the tags... Test can be on [cpp.sh](http://cpp.sh)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::string algorithm_sorting ("1101001011");
    std::vector <std::string> video = {"a1","a2","a3","a4"};
    std::vector <std::string> picture = {"b1","b2","b3","b4"};
    std::vector <std::string> result;
    size_t v = 0, p = 0;
    for(auto&x:algorithm_sorting)
    {
        if(x=='1')
        {
            if(v < video.size()) result.push_back(video[v]);
            v++;
        }
        else
        {
            if( p < picture.size()) result.push_back(picture[p]);
            p++;
        }
    }
    for(auto&x:result)std::cout<<x<<" ";
}
```

Comment: Didn't notice it at first, my bad.

Comment: ya, i wanted php & c++ lang